# What's the most efficient way to structure this error handling?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting user input from a web form as follows:

```
Dim t_ResolvedID As TextBox = DirectCast(gvrow.FindControl("editResolved"), TextBox)
Dim t_CommentsID As TextBox = DirectCast(gvrow.FindControl("editComments"), TextBox)
```

I would like to limit acceptable input as follows:

- t_ResolvedID should only be a positive whole number (no alpha characters)
- t_CommentsID should not exceed 4000 characters.  Additionally, if t_CommentsID.Text contains a single quote, replace it with two single quotes

As of now, I'm performing this error handling as follows:

```
If IsNumeric(t_ResolvedID.Text) Then
    resolved = Integer.Parse(t_ResolvedID.Text)
Else
    ShowMessage("Error!  Invalid character in 'Resolved' field.")
    errorCount += 1
End If

If Integer.Parse(t_ResolvedID.Text) < 0 Then
    ShowMessage("Error!  'Resolved' field cannot be negative!")
    errorCount += 1
End If

If t_CommentsID.Text.Length > 4000 Then
    errorCount += 1
    ShowMessage("Error!  The 'Comments' field cannot exceed 4000 characters!")
End If

'Transform single quote into two single quotes to avoid SQL errors
If t_CommentsID.Text.Contains("'") Then
    comments = t_CommentsID.Text.Replace("'", "''")
End If

If t_CommentsID.Text.Length < 4000 And Not t_CommentsID.Text.Contains("'") Then
    comments = t_CommentsID.Text
End If
```

I feel like there's a better way to do it, though.  Right now, I'm only keeping an error count because I DON'T want to perform the final update SQL query with bad data.  So I check if errorCount is equal to 0 before running the query.  How can I make this more efficient?

I'm using AJAX for the ShowMessage() function, so I'd like to keep the ability to notify users of errors if possible.

Thank you!

EDIT:  I ended up modifying my code as follows:

```
If Not IsNumeric(t_ResolvedID.Text) Then
    errors += "Error!  Invalid character in 'Resolved' field<br/>"
Else
    resolved = Integer.Parse(t_ResolvedID.Text)
    If resolved < 0 Then
        errors += "Error!  'Resolved' field cannot be negative!<br/>"
    Else
        resolved = t_ResolvedID.Text
    End If
End If

If t_CommentsID.Text.Length > 4000 Then
    'errorCount += 1
    errors += "Error!  'Comments' field cannot exceed 4000 characters!<br/>"
End If

'Transform single quote into two single quotes to avoid SQL errors
If t_CommentsID.Text.Contains("'") Then
    comments = t_CommentsID.Text.Replace("'", "''")
End If

If t_CommentsID.Text.Length < 4000 And Not t_CommentsID.Text.Contains("'") Then
    comments = t_CommentsID.Text

End If
```

Comment: I dont find anything too wrong with your code. You should reuse "resolved" rather than parsing the string again in your second test. And you may want to concatenate all of your messages and show them all together at the end. You may also want to look at some validation controls for a more professional look, but you could spend days on that, not sure what your target audience is.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  Obviously, parsing the string once will lead to better performance, I'll make that change.  Also, concatenating strings and then showing them all at the end is a great idea.  What do you mean by validation controls, though?  My target audience consists of mostly accountants, the web site basically grabs numbers from a database, does some math, and outputs that to the user in a GridView.

Comment: take a look here at [MSDN validation controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you for that resource.  I'm fairly new to ASP.NET so this is new to me.  My last question--if the user enters a decimal number, it generates an exception because I'm trying to use `Integer.Parse()`.  I would rather just handle the error.  Is there anyway to account for that in my modified code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
If Not IsNumeric(intString) Then
    errors += "Error!  Invalid character in 'Resolved' field<br/>"
Else
    If Not Integer.TryParse(intString, resolved) Then
        errors += "Error!  Resolved must be an integer."
    End If
end if
```